# What is an Ajax call: 'success' or 'failure'?

Tags: jquery, ajax

This seems 101-level, but I can't find an answer!  (instead I find links to what to do on success or failures, jQuery's `ajax().success` and the like.

My hunch is:

- `success`:  200 HTTP return code
- `failure`:  anything else.

Comment: Just a case of more general question "What is a HTTP call succes/failure"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not really an AJAX, but jQuery question, because the success callback is only characteristic of jQuery, not AJAX on the whole.

From the jQuery source you can see how it is implemented

```
// If successful, handle type chaining
            if ( status >= 200 && status < 300 || status === 304 ) {

                // Set the If-Modified-Since and/or If-None-Match header, if in ifModified mode.
                if ( s.ifModified ) {

                    if ( ( lastModified = jqXHR.getResponseHeader( "Last-Modified" ) ) ) {
                        jQuery.lastModified[ ifModifiedKey ] = lastModified;
                    }
                    if ( ( etag = jqXHR.getResponseHeader( "Etag" ) ) ) {
                        jQuery.etag[ ifModifiedKey ] = etag;
                    }
                }

                // If not modified
                if ( status === 304 ) {

                    statusText = "notmodified";
                    isSuccess = true;

...
else fail with the error callback
```

So, basically if the HTTP response code is between 200 and 299 (inclusive) or 304 it goes for the `success` callback, otherwise, it is the `error` callback.

Comment: fair critique of my question!  Thanks for pointing to the relevant part of jQ itself.

Comment: same here: 

print 'OK' if $status =~ /^(2|304)/;

Answer (score 1):

an ajax call returns 1 of 4 different readystates (4 is the important one where data is received)

as well as the status, which can be any of of the normal response statuses (200 is no errors)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

a useful example:

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_first