# Will Deferred.fail() be triggered if the server respond with 401/402 status?

Tags: javascript, jquery, http

The document says fail() is triggered *when the Deferred object is rejected.*

However this sounds rather vague and I cant quite understand when will it be triggered from the HTTP perspective. Will all 400/500 status code eventually fall into the fail() handler?

Comment: You could find out by giving it a try.

Comment: black box test does not explain the logic and design behind it

Comment: yes for `$.ajax` but also other errors like parse errors , timeout, no connection will cause rejection

Comment: Closely related question/answer: [What is an Ajax call: 'success' or 'failure'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8773276/what-is-an-ajax-call-success-or-failure)

Answer (score 2):

**Edited for Clarity:**

This line in the jQuery source will tell you how `jQuery` respects HTTP semantics:

```
    isSuccess = status >= 200 && status < 300 || status === 304;
```

https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js#L722

**Original Answer:**

4xx and 5xx are HTTP error codes. jQuery ajax will fire a fail event for all of them.

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

It will not fail for successful (2xx) responses. jQuery will also follow redirection (3xx) status codes so they will not be deemed errors either unless the redirect it follows yields a 4xx or 5xx status.

As carhlietfl pointed out in the comments, a successful (2xx) response could still fire a fail event if the response from the server is not what you told jQuery to expect - e.g. if you said `dataType:'json'` and sent back something other than `JSON` (including improperly formatted `JSON`) then you're fail callback will also get called.

Comment: not 100% true about 200, if dataType is json and xml or html gets returned for example will  have a fail trigger. Also jsonp requests that don't return jsonp can be 200

Comment: It was my fault not asking the question in the way I want it to be answered. I've read through the link you provided before asking, but still confused on if/how HTTP semantics are respected in jQuery. Thanks a lot for taking time helping me tho, up voted and appreciated.

Comment: @miushock - check my edited answer for the line in the `jQuery` source that will answer your question.